# Wait for activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a question about life cycle.

I have 2 activities. (Just call it A and B).
In A which is `MainActivity` I have a `button` that call Activity B.
At activity B, pressing back button will call the `finish()`.

The point is it's okay when I call `finish()`, wait a while and than call B again, it's okay.
But when I call `finish()` and immediately call B again than
previous B's `onDestroy()` is called *after* new B's `onCreate()`, `onResume()`.

It's problem for me because I handle some static `MediaPlayer` on `onResume()`, `onPause()`... everywhere.

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if (mediaPlayer != null)
        mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    if(mediaPlayer != null)
        mediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mediaPlayer != null)
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

So if I press back and call B fast again, it resume the previous sound short and than stop.
Another class controls the `mediaPlayer` so I can't remove the *static* field.

I think I can handle this by waiting `onDestroy(`).
Is there any way to make MainActivity(A) to wait until B is completely destroyed?

Comment: Can't you just release mediaPlayer before finish() manually? As you already check for null this shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `ActivityLifeCycleCallBack Listner` for Application class, where you can know Which activity is *created* and which is *Destroyed*.

This will help you to easily implement your current logic [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce counted lock, like:

```
class X extends Activity {

    private static int runningTimes = 0;

    private synchronized void lockPlayer() {
        ++runningTimes;
    }

    private synchronized boolean releasePlayer() {
        return (0 == --runningTimes);
    }

    @Override
    onCreate(...) {
        super.onCreate(...);
        lockPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        if(releasePlayer() && mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

I think both Activities run on the same UI thread in onCreate/onDestroy? Because that proposed synchronization is not robust enough to survive truly parallel execution. If they are on the same UI thread, actually the `synchronized` can be removed from ++/-- methods, as only the order of onCreate/onDestroy is problem, not simultaneous run of them.

I would also suggest to call `super.on<EndingEvent>()` to call at the end of your overridden handler, not at the start of it (you will probably never encounter real bug from this, but it just makes sense, if you read the source "procedurally" in mind).

---

Warning: in case you don't receive correctly paired onCreate/onDestroy, the counter may get into unsynced value... probably it wouldn't do much harm, as you will simply not release the player ever then. But I have generally good experience with Android OS calling onCreate/onDestroy reliably, except situations when whole OS is already on the brink of crash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over when `onDestroy()` gets called, so waiting for that will not work.

In your case you should either call `mediaPlayer.release()` in `onPause()` and create it in `onResume()`, or just leave it existing independently of the lifecycle of the activities

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this could work:

```
class B extends Activity {
     public static boolean destroyed = 1;
     .
     .
     .
     public void onCreate(Bundle args) {
          destroyed = 0;
          .
          .
          .
     }
     public void onDestroy() {
          .
          .
          .
          destroyed = 1;
     }
}
class A extends Activity {
     .
     .
     .
     buttonB.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              while (B.destroyed == 0);
              Intent i = new Intent();
              .
              .
              .
              startActivity(i, B.class);
          }

     })
}
```

The   "B.destroyed == 0" part will wait until B is destroyed, and then it will start the new intent.

Note: there's also isDestroyed() method starting from API17 which you can call on activity B, smth like: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed()

Comment: well.. isn't this contain potential ANR ??

Comment: The button is placed in Activity A, and B is destroyed in less than 1 second. I don't see how this can throw an ANR ?

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer.